# No encuentro el preventDefault

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

Estoy haciendo un formulario simple, el cual contiene un input y un botón. Estoy usando `preventDefault()` para detener la ejecución del formulario. Quise revisar un poco mas sobre el tema y ver la función en si, pero no la encuentro.

Tengo la función normal que es la que recibe el `submit`:

```js
const onSubmit = (event) =>{
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(event)
}
```

En la consola me aparecen varios métodos, pero lo mas cercano que me aparece es un `isDefaultPrevented`. Entonces, ¿Dónde esta el método `preventDefault`?, ¿No se supone que al mostrar el evento en consola me deberían aparecer todos?. Adjunto una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En qué navegador? Nombre y versión, por favor

Comment: busca en 'nativeEvent' el prototipo 'Event' y dentro mira si se encuentra 'preventDefault'... estas usando React?

Comment: Dentro del prototipo Event aparece la funcion preventDefault()...

Answer (score 1):

El preventDefault() lo dispara un evento no la function que estas creando.

ejemplo

```js
    unBoton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        onSubmit(e);
    });    
    const onSubmit = (event) =>{
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log(event)
    }
```

```html
 <button id="unBoton">prueba</button>
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

para obtener el evento, es mejor que lo hagas con addEventListener, eso se consigue, llamando al elemento que le quieres capturar un evento, en tu caso, el boton.

codigo en HTML

```html
<button id="boton"> Evitar Defecto </button>
```

codigo en JavaScript

```js
const boton = document.getElementByID('boton');
```

```js
boton.addEventListener('click', ( evento ) => {
    evento.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Mi aporte***

Y como dice Joan `PreventDefault` lo ejecuta un evento en este caso un botón

***JS***

```
const btn = document.getElementById("bt-send")

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e)
})
```

***HTML***

```
<button type="submit" id="bt-send">ENVIAR</button>
```

Con `console.log(e)` obtendrás la siguiente salida>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vas a desplegar `[[Prototype]] : PointerEvent` luego te va hasta el final y despliegas `[[Prototype]] : MouseEvent` luego `[[Prototype]] : UIEvent` y para finalizar `[[Prototype]] : Event`

Obtendrás la siguiente vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]